# iOS Autocorrect in Textview

Tags: ios, mobile, textview

In Apple's Messages app, if you make a typo, the little correction bubble shows up. Before you hit space, this bubble lets you know that any further activity (spacebar or submit button) without dismissing the bubble will result in the autocorrection.

I have a text submission form in my app - but in my app, when the user tries to submit the textview while the autocorrect bubble is up, the textview will NOT take the autocorrection. How do I make it take the autocorrection and THEN submit?

Screenshot of the autocorrect bubble.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdEAs.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `[self.view endEditing:YES]` when you "submit" the text view where `self` is the view controller containing the text view.

The call to `endEditing:` will ensure the proper chain of events occur resulting in the text view's text being updated properly. This is what I do in my app.

Comment: This will resign all first responders in the view, which causes the keyboard to disappear. Is there any way to get the desired effect while keeping the keyboard up?